Add More Subsections in Pandoc PDF
I am having an issue with Pandoc where I want to include more subsections in my PDF. I have found that the toc-depth variable can increase the number of heading levels from 3 to 5, but I need more than five levels.
Here is the command I am running:
pandoc example.md -o example.pdf --template eisvogel --from markdown --toc -V titlepage=true --listings --pdf-engine=xelatex -V toc-depth=10

And here is the content of example.md:
---
title:  Test
date:  2024/07/29
version:  v0.0.1
---

# 1. Top Level

## 1.1. First Sublevel

### 1.1.1. Second Sublevel

#### 1.1.1.1. Third Sublevel

##### 1.1.1.1.1. Fourth Sublevel

###### 1.1.1.1.1.1. Fifth Sublevel

####### 1.1.1.1.1.1.1. Sixth Sublevel

######## 1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1. Seventh Sublevel

######### 1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1. Eighth Sublevel

########## 1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1. Ninth Sublevel

########### 1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1. Tenth Sublevel

I expect the output to include all 10 levels of headings, but it seems to be limited to only five levels. I have also tried editing the LaTeX template to handle deeper levels, but the problem persists.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I don't think it's possible to do that, mainly because LaTeX doesn't support it. From a typographic stand point, deep nesting like that should be absolutely discouraged. If one needs to count the number of ones in the section number, then something is wrong.
One thing to try is to call pandoc with --top-level-division=part, this will add support for two additional levels, but it might not work with the Eisvogel template.
You could also switch to a different PDF engine, such as ConTeXt. That could probably be mended more easily to support a monstrosity like that. See also this Q&A on tex.SE.
